# why I getting npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js

when I tried npm install on vs terminal getting below error

```
PS C:\Users\asmahajan\ashvini\ums> npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\asmahajan\ashvini\ums/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\asmahajan\ashvini\ums\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I have setup project, and install node.js and angular 14
and now in visual studio on terminal i tried for npm install cammand
but getting error

Comment: Check in the folder ums, do you have the package.json file ?! Do a cat command / type based on your operatiing system. i.e,. type package.json . Verify whether file exist, then you run the npm install. If its still not working, then try it in normal cmd prompt